# Missingness mechanism for multiple imputation of thousands of variables

Tags: missing-data

I have a database with 186 observations and 1782 variables that you can access using the following R code:

```r
# Specify the URL of the CSV file
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/D-PLACE/dplace-data/master/datasets/SCCS/data.csv"

# Read the CSV file from the URL
data <- read_csv(url)

# Remove columns that are not needed for analysis
data_analysis <- data %>% 
  select(soc_id, var_id, code)

# Pivot the data to wide format
data_wide <- data_analysis %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var_id, values_from = code)

# Declaration of types
url2 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/D-PLACE/dplace-data/master/datasets/SCCS/variables.csv"
variables <- read_csv(url2) %>% select(id, type)
variables <- rbind(variables, list("soc_id","Categorical"))
variables$id <- as.factor(variables$id)
variables$type <- as.factor(variables$type)
summary(variables)

# Iterate through each column name in data_wide
for (col_name in colnames(data_wide)) {
  # Find the corresponding row in variables using id
  variable_row <- variables[variables$id == col_name, ]
  
  # Check the type value for the current column
  col_type <- variable_row$type
  
  # Convert column to the appropriate type
  if (col_type == "Categorical") {
    data_wide[[col_name]] <- as.factor(data_wide[[col_name]])
  } else if (col_type == "Ordinal") {
    data_wide[[col_name]] <- as.ordered(data_wide[[col_name]])
  } else if (col_type == "Continuous") {
    # No need to change anything for continuous variables
  } else {
    # Handle any other cases or error handling here
  }
}

# Check the reshaped data
summary(data_wide)

sum(is.na(data_wide))/(nrow(data_wide)*ncol(data_wide))
```

As you can see, 46% of all values are missing. From interviewing specialists, it seems the missing mechanism is NMAR and that most missing values will be at the center or mode of the distribution of each variable. This is because the database is about the documentation of cultures around the world, and most ethnographies from the time tend to mention the exotic parts of cultures while not mentioning the most typical.

Because of the amount of missing data, their distribution and their presumed missingness mechanism, analysis of complete cases seems a terrible idea. So I will have to impute.

But to impute I have to model the mechanism and for that, I should have it clearer. Does it just suffice to rely on the specialist's hunches, or should I use other methods to diagnose it? If so, how do I do so when I have so many variables? Visualisation seems impossible with 1782 variables. Also, something that has always confused me: The proposed mechanism is for the whole database or for each variable? I.e.: VarX1 is MAR, while VarX2 is NMAR and so on?

If I just use the specialist's hunch and go directly to claim all the database as NMAR, how do I model the missing mechanism? Just with an offset and a sensibility analysis on what the offset is?